# Can I use "useToken=true" and "withForm" in login form using spring security plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a grails application that uses spring security plugin authentication.

Until now I have been protecting all my forms against CSRF attacks using `useToken=true` and verifying this in the controller with `withForm` block, but I don't know how to do this in my login form that uses spring security plugin.

Is there any possibility to use `useToken` in the login form and then override some spring security class to be able to use `withForm` in grails?

How can I protect login against CSRF attacks?

These are my changes to login to be able to use useToken.

**MyLoginController**

```
def checkLogin(){
        withForm {
            redirect(uri: "/j_spring_security_check", params: params)
        }.invalidToken{
            message(error: "Double submit error")
        }

    }
```

**GSP**

```
<g:form action='checkLogin' method='POST' id='loginForm' autocomplete='off' useToken="true">
<input id="username" name="j_username" type="text">
<input id="password" name="j_password" type="password"
<button data-dismiss="modal" type="submit"</button>
</g:form>
```

This give me an username and password error and do not redirect me to my after login page.

Now, this is my previous code that works perfectly, using the default spring security behavior. No custom login controller and this in the gsp.

```
<form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm' autocomplete='off'>
```

Comment: CSRF only works if the user is already logged in. It doesn't make sense to protect your login form for CSRF

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your answer, i just read that, yes, is possible https://support.detectify.com/customer/portal/articles/1969819-login-csrf